# CSV using '-' as NULL. Error to convert column to INT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nul

I have a CSV

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4068744 | -1472525 | 2596219 |
| 198366 | - | - |

The file is using '-' for nul values

I tried converting to int without handling that '-'.

My question is: how do I strip the string '-' without changing the negative values?

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].astype(int)
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Answer (score 0):

Higher version of `pandas` can hold `integer` dtypes with missing values. Normal `int` conversion doesn't support null values.

```
# replace - with null
df.replace('-', pd.NA, inplace=True)
# and use Int surrounding with ''
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].astype('Int64')
```

output:

```
> df

  Column A  Column B Column C
0  4068744  -1472525  2596219
1   198366      <NA>     <NA>

> df['Column B'].info

Name: Column B, dtype: Int64>
```